# Simple harmonic motion, maximum kinetic energy

Tags: energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

Why kinetic energy is maximum at mean position?

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213246/2451

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research-effort.

Answer (score 1):

The mean position of a projectile in circular motion is the lowermost point. This is the point with the lowest potential energy. That means, by the conservation of mechanical energy, that the kinetic energy (and hence the speed) is the highest.

This analysis applies to any system (ignoring friction) at the point where the potential energy is the lowest, the kinetic energy and the speed are the highest. Many systems (for example a weight on a spring in SHM) have the lowest point of potential energy at the mean position, and it is for these systems that the highest kinetic energy is at the mean position.

I hope this answered your question.